# How to control the currently running music (from Spotify for example) from my iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I would like to implement a feature into my app where I can play/pause/skip the currently running music on the iPhone doesn't matter whether the music is playing from Spotify or Apple music.

Bose has this kind of feature in their app.

Does anyone know how to implement something like this.

Comment: Can Bose app control audio from another app if the audio is playing through the built in phone speaker? Or are they simply controlling their Hardwares/headsets?

Comment: I believe `AVAudioPlayer` can do what you're looking for: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer

Comment: I think you actually want media player; although I have never tried it on third party apps: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer

Comment: The Bose app can control the audio of the system.  It also knows the song title and artist from Spotify.

Comment: Bose is most likely using the combination of the iOS MediaPlayer and the Spotify API https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/